# C, How to save String into binary file?

Tags: mysql, c, binary, binaryfiles

I want to save String array to binary file.
I searched and tried, didn't come up with normal binary file contents.
(not like 00 0A 10) came up with (8죅?  <죅?  A죅?  E죅?) - written in korean.

the writing part of the code was

```
FILE *fp_course = fopen("KJH_course.dat", "wb");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {      //JUST FOR FETCHING DATA FROM MYSQL, WORKED WELL
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]);
        fwrite(row, sizeof(row), 1, fp_course);
};
```

the data in row is {'32141183', 'JHK', '2'}
(the last row[3] was used for larger array later)

did i wrote something wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it like this? Hint: the `sizeof` operator does not do what you think. Google it.

Comment: It's homework on my class, it should be written in binary file :(

Comment: Text in binary file is not that special.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this, still need to finish it for my grade.....

Comment: what is `row`, as returned by `mysql_fetch_row(res);` ? What is its type ?

Comment: @joop It's a `char **` pointer, each pointer in it points to a string. Search the documentation online.

Comment: @joop this script is for getting DB from mysql, i tried to get it by pointer into array, actually worked. still having trouble with writing into binary file.

Comment: plain text is already binary.

Answer (score 4):

The `sizeof` operator does not return the length of a string, I suppose that `row` is a pointer, `sizeof` it is simply the size of a pointer, you can't do what you want the way you tried.

You need the length of each item, so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; ++i) {
    fwrite(row[i], 1, strlen(row[i]), fp_course);
}
```

#### VERY IMPORTANT NOTE

The contents written to the file this way, are **useless**, because you don't know the length of each string so there is no way to read them back.

So perhaps you are required to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; ++i) {
    char *string;
    int length;

    string = row[i];
    length = strlen(string);

    fwrite(&length, sizeof(length), 1, fp_course);
    fwrite(string, 1, length, fp_course);
}
```

this way you can read the data back.

Comment: or: add a null terminator

Answer (score 4):

The [MySQL documentation has an example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html):

```c
MYSQL_ROW row;
unsigned int num_fields;
unsigned int i;

num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
   unsigned long *lengths;
   lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
   for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
   {
       printf("[%.*s] ", (int) lengths[i],
              row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Note that `MYSQL_ROW` returned does not necessarily have nul terminated *strings* (as per a comment, quoted below), so you can't safely call `strlen()` on the columns - instead you have to call `mysql_fetch_lengths()`.

> MYSQL_ROW is an array of null-terminated strings. (However, you cannot treat these as null-terminated strings if field values may contain binary data, because such values may contain null bytes internally.)